# Challenges to constructing a "building" in Earth orbit (something like a hotel) 100% robotically?

Tags: uncrewed-spaceflight, robotic-missions, robotics, tourism, reduced-gravity-manufacturing

Today my younger brother and I, while discussing the idea of building any commercial building (something like a hotel) in the Earth orbit, got into some debate with the assembling of the building in space.

I believe it won't be possible to build any building or any craft in space without **physical** presence of any human in space but he thinks otherwise, says that it's completely possible with humans controlling things right from Earth. But I think a physical presence is very much necessary to ensure everything goes right and even fix problems from there only when needed.

What would be the challenges to constructing a "building" in Earth orbit (something like a hotel) 100% robotically, without any local human supervision, i.e. nobody up there in orbit to keep an eye on things or fix things when they break?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Before this was migrated I'd adjusted the wording a bit to better fit the Stack Exchange format (i.e. "what do you think?" can't have fact-based answers).

Comment: The US side of the ISS was assembled robotically with operators in the adjacent spacecraft. Then EVA people hooked up cables, lines, etc. I see nothing insurmountable about remote robotic assembly  given proper design.

Comment: Step one: demonstrate robotic construction of a building on Earth’s surface.

Comment: The Soviet Union performed a few completely uncrewed dockings. So if you understand "constructing" as "joining pieces that were pre-made on Earth, then I see no issues there.